# WANT $1 prom regex with prag match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have a string like

```
<div id="gallery">                        
<ul id="new_img_gallery" class="imgul">
{{<li id="">     <div class="img"> <a target="_blank" href="#"><img width="110" height="90" src="http://192.168.1.47/evm/wp-content/plugins/models_new/myuploads/1415115672-9f03f297346252c5628b0eb795960d66.jpg" alt="Klematis"></a>
<div class="desc"><a><input type="radio" value="1" name="profile">profile</a><a class="removebutton " id="307">remove</a></div></div></li> 

<li id="">
 <div class="img"> <a target="_blank" href="#"><img width="110" height="90" src="http://192.168.1.47/evm/wp-content/plugins/models_new/myuploads/1415115672-00016c42b36b12a0f3d818(1).jpg" alt="Klematis"></a>

<div class="desc"><a><input type="radio" value="1" name="profile">profile</a><a class="removebutton " id="308">remove</a></div></div></li> 

<li id=""> <div class="img"> <a target="_blank" href="#"><img width="110" height="90" src="http://192.168.1.47/evm/wp-content/plugins/models_new/myuploads/1415115673-00016c42b36b12a0f3d818.jpg" alt="Klematis"></a>       
 <div class="desc"><a><input type="radio" value="1" name="profile">profile</a><a class="removebutton " id="309">remove</a></div>     </div> </li> 

 <li id=""> <div class="img"> <a target="_blank" href="#"><img width="110" height="90" src="http://192.168.1.47/evm/wp-content/plugins/models_new/myuploads/1415115673-24th_Escort.png" alt="Klematis"></a>
 <div class="desc"><a><input type="radio" value="1" name="profile">profile</a><a class="removebutton " id="310">remove</a></div></div> </li> 

 <li id=""> 
<div class="img"> <a target="_blank" href="#"><img width="110" height="90" src="http://192.168.1.47/evm/wp-content/plugins/models_new/myuploads/1415115699-00016c42b36b12a0f3d818(1).jpg" alt="Klematis"></a>       
<div class="desc"><a><input type="radio" value="1" name="profile">profile</a><a class="removebutton " id="311">remove</a></div>     </div> </li>
}}</ul>
```

Now thing is how can i get the Everything in between the **curly  bracket**({{or}}) but not the **curly bracket**

I have the wrote regexp  **/{{(.+)}}/gi**
but its wont work and how can i get the **$1 position** in js

Comment: are you running js or php?

Comment: try `{{(.+?)}}` . Could you remove all the `>` symbols at the start?

Answer (score 0):

```
{{([\s\S]*)}}
```

Your regex is correct but you have not specified `s` or `DOTALL` flag.That flag is not avialable in javascript.So you need to use `\s\S` to handle all newlines.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/64